# How do I tell CSV to make a column instead of a row?

Tags: ruby, csv

I wrote a very simple program with Nokogiri to scrape a website and create a CSV file. It is getting the correct data and making the CSV, but the data is pushed into one cell (A1), and I would rather it come out as a column, with each value separated by a comma.

How do I tell CSV to make a column for each value separated by a comma instead of putting all the info into a single cell?

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'csv'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open('somewebpage.com'))
CSV.open("webpagedata.csv", "wb") do |csv|
    data = doc.css('.information h3 a').map { |link| link['href']  }
    puts data
    csv << [data]
end
```

Comment: This isn't a Nokogiri problem, because Nokogiri doesn't create CSV data. You have to coerce the NodeSet returned by `css` and `map` into the format you want CSV to receive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result from `doc.css('.information h3 a').map { |link| link['href']  }` is already an array, so when you add it to your CSV file you don’t need to wrap it in `[...]`.

Change the line

```
csv << [data]
```

to

```
csv << data
```

The CSV library deals mainly in rows, so if you want to create a *column* rather than a *row*, then you need to add a (single entry) row for each entry of the column:

```
CSV.open("webpagedata.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  data = doc.css('.information h3 a').map { |link| link['href']  }
  data.each do |entry|
    csv << [entry]
  end
end
```

Note that in this case you *do* need the `[...]` around the `entry`, as you need to add an array not a single item.

Comment: This worked! It got all my data into separate cells in a row, and it's fairly simple to make it a column in Excel. Thanks! I tried to upvote your answer, but I don't have enough reputation. Excuse my noobishness.

Comment: @Guyana.Hand I’ve added one way you could create a column directly